# Which repo is rsnapshot in on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos6, package-management

I have enabled the epel and remi repositories, but:

```
yum install rsnapshot
```

produces

```
No package rsnapshot available.
```

rsnapshot was in EPEL on prior versions... was it removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RepoForge repo: http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rsnapshot/

Comment: Is rsnapshot no longer in the repositories?

Comment: I think yes, because I watch it in EPEL for 5.x. But I don't know why. rsnapshot is stable enough. RepoForge is ex-RPMForge (it was renamed). You can try to use this repo with yum protectbase plugin if you afraid to non-consistent updates. Thanks.

Comment: It hasn't been added to the default repositories, no. You'll have to add the RPMforge repository. [Instructions can be found here.](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge/#head-f0c3ecee3dbb407e4eed79a56ec0ae92d1398e01)

Comment: For completeness, you need to install some dependencies first `yum install perl rsync wget perl-DBI perl-XML-Simple perl-XML-Filter-BufferText`. You also need to get the XML-Validator-Schema package, which doesn't appear to have a repo package for it either, `wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/perl-XML-Validator-Schema/perl-XML-Validator-Schema-1.10-1.el6.rf.noarch.rpm` and then `rpm -ivh perl-XML-Validator-Schema-1.10-1.el6.rf.noarch.rpm`.

Comment: Or maybe adding the RPMforge per your comment could be done instead of the instructions in my comment since it would likely resolve and install it's own dependencies? I got it installed now though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rsnapshot is in the Fedora Repositories, however it looks like it hasn't been built for RHEL6, and the last RHEL5 build appears to be from 2009.

[Fedora Package Details](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/rsnapshot)

If anything it looks like the package is in need of some love and attention again.  This looks  like a good chance for someone to get more involved in the open source community!